# Script for Google Spreadsheets - Copying tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macros, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a script for Google Spreadsheets that, through a custom menu in my target spreadsheet (SS):

1. Reads all the spreadsheets included in my Drive folder named "My folder" (ID: XXX).
2. From all those spreadsheets including a tab named "ALL", copy all the content in those "ALL" tabs as values (this is important as those tabs include formulas).
3. Creates a new tab in my target spreadsheet for earch of the ALL tabs from the source spreadsheets and name them "1", "2", "3", "4",...
4. Pastes those copied values in these newly created tabs.

However, I only get it to create the new tabs without copying the data or to copy the whole tab duplicating it, hence formulas as copied as formulas and #REF is generated.

These are the scripts that I have created so far and their issues:

1- Using an onOpen trigger, this one creates the new tabs in the target SS but does not copy the content of the source tab into the new tab.

```
function onFileAdded(e) {
  var folderId = "[MY FOLDER ID]"; 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var sheetName = file.getName();
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[MY TARGET SPREADSHEET ID]"); 
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    if (sheet == null) {
      sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
    }

    
    var originalSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("[NAME OF THE TAB TO BE COPIED FROM THE SOURCE SPREADSHEET - CURRENTLY "ALL"]"); 
    var sourceRange = originalSheet.getRange("[RANGE TO BE COPIED]"); //Copying the whole tab would also be OK.
    var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceRange.getNumRows(), sourceRange.getNumColumns());
    sourceRange.copyTo(destinationRange);
```

2- Using a custom menu, this script copies the whole source ALL tabs from a certain folder into my target SS, but they are "duplicated" so to say, so the formulae generate teh #REF error as they originally reference other tabs in the source SS:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('[NAME OF THE MENU]')
      .addItem('[NAME OF THE ITEM]', 'copyTabFromNewSheets')
      .addToUi();
}

function copyTabFromNewSheets() {
  var folderId = '[SOURCE FOLDER ID]';

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  var files = folder.getFiles();

  var targetSpreadsheetId = '[TARGET SPREADSHEET ID]';

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    if (file.getMimeType() === MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
      
      var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('[NAME OF THE TAB I WANT TO COPY THE CONTENT FROM - CURRENTLY "ALL"]');
      
      var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
      
      var newSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(targetSpreadsheet);
      
      newSheet.setName(spreadsheet.getName());
      
    }
  }
}
```

Could anyone help with this?

Thank you SO MUCH in advance

Comment: I don't know how many spreadsheets you have on your drive but in my account something like that would take days and it  would be totally ludicrous to even consider.  So how many spreadsheets are we talking about?

Comment: `I am trying to create a script` Would you please edit your question to include the scripts that you are trying to use.

Comment: Hi! Firstly, thank you both so much for your comments and interest :)

@Cooper: Currently I do not have many SSs, but I do expect to have many (cannot specify a fixed number though) in the near future and I wanted to avoid having to manually transfer these data.

Comment: @Tedinoz: Sure thing! My original question has been udpated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

(the copied content is pasted as values, not formulas, to avoid `#REF` errors)

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Copy ALL Tabs', 'copyAllTabs')
      .addToUi();
}

function copyAllTabs() {
  var folderId = 'FOLDER_ID';
  var targetSpreadsheetId = 'SHEET_ID';

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  
  // Get a list of files in the source folder
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
  
  // Initialize a counter for naming sheets in the target spreadsheet
  var sheetCounter = 1;

  // Iterate through the files in the folder
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    
    if (file.getMimeType() === MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
      // Access the 'ALL' sheet in the source spreadsheet
      var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ALL');

      if (sourceSheet) {
        var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

        // Create a new sheet with a name based on the counter
        var newSheetName = sheetCounter.toString();
        var newSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(newSheetName);

        // Check if a sheet with the same name already exists in the target spreadsheet
        while (newSheet) {
          sheetCounter++;
          newSheetName = sheetCounter.toString();
          newSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(newSheetName);
        }

        // Create a new sheet with a unique name
        newSheet = targetSpreadsheet.insertSheet(newSheetName);
        
        var targetRange = newSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length);
        targetRange.setValues(values);
        
        sheetCounter++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```